# How do i change background in all elements of RecyclerView to a SharedPreferences saved color?

Tags: java, android, xml, sharedpreferences

I have a PreferenceScreen wher i save some parameters, and i want to use this parameters to change the visual of all the elements of my recyclerview located elsewhere in the app.

I don't know how or where to put the values to set this preferences when the elements are created.

All the elements of the Recycler consist in an horizontal linearLayout with some Textview; and i want to change the background color of the layout and the textcolor of the textview (with the preference values)

I tried to recover and pass this data from the view where the RecyclerView is located, but i don't know how to do that in the adapter instead

This is the adapter code

```java
public class Adaptagrande extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adaptagrande.jHolder>{

    List<Juego> jueguiss;
    private Context micontext;

    public Adaptagrande(Context micontext, List<Juego> jueguiss){
        this.jueguiss = jueguiss;
        this.micontext = micontext;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public jHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup grupo, int i){
        View vv = LayoutInflater.from(grupo.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_juegofull, grupo, false);
        jHolder holdeer = new jHolder(vv);

        return holdeer;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final jHolder holder, final int pos){
        final Juego j1 = jueguiss.get(pos);
        holder.titxtlist.setText(j1.getTitulo());
        holder.platxtlist.setText(j1.getPlataforma());
        holder.posetxtlist.setText(j1.getPosesion());
        holder.formatxtlist.setText(j1.getFisico());
        holder.avatxtlist.setText(j1.getAvance());
        holder.vectxtlist.setText(j1.getVeces());
        //cargapref();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return jueguiss.size();
    }

    public static class jHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView titxtlist;
        public TextView platxtlist;
        public TextView posetxtlist;
        public TextView formatxtlist;
        public TextView avatxtlist;
        public TextView vectxtlist;

        //SharedPreferences preferences;

        public jHolder(View itemViewer){
            super(itemViewer);
            titxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titxtlist);
            platxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.platxtlist);
            posetxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.posetxtlist);
            formatxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.formatxtlist);
            avatxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.avatxtlist);
            vectxtlist=(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.vectxtlist);


        }
    }
}
```

this is the XML of every element in the recycler

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#505050"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#C4E0E0E0"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contene2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#525252"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/titxtlist"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/platxtlist"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/posetxtlist"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/formatxtlist"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/avatxtlist"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/vectxtlist"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFF" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#C4E0E0E0"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the xml file for preferences and the class

```java
public class SettingFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {


    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle bundle, String s) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, s);
    }


}
```

```xml
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Visual lista grande">


        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entries="@array/colorsfondo"
            android:entryValues="@array/colorsfondo"
            android:key="list_preference_1"
            android:title="Color de fondo" />
    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

If i recover data anywhere else or modifiy the selection in the PreferenceScreen it works properly.

If I am able to recover the string element from the preferences and through an "if" statement or "Switch - case" change the background color it would be perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay i fixed it

In the Adapter class (Adaptagrande), on the onBindViewHolder, added this method

```java
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final jHolder holder, final int pos){
        final Juego j1 = jueguiss.get(pos);
        holder.titxtlist.setText(j1.getTitulo());
        holder.platxtlist.setText(j1.getPlataforma());
        holder.posetxtlist.setText(j1.getPosesion());
        holder.formatxtlist.setText(j1.getFisico());
        holder.avatxtlist.setText(j1.getAvance());
        holder.vectxtlist.setText(j1.getVeces());
        cargapref(holder);
    }

    private void cargapref(jHolder holder) {

        final String backgrndcolor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(micontext).getString("list_preference_1", "");
        final String textcolor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(micontext).getString("list_preference_2","");


        switch (backgrndcolor){
            case "Naranja" :
                holder.contenedor.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,255, 139, 30));
                break;
            case "Rojo" :
                holder.contenedor.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,255, 0, 0));
                break;
            case "Amarillo" :
                holder.contenedor.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,255, 255, 0));
                break;
            case "Verde" :
                holder.contenedor.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,0, 255, 0));
                break;
            case "Azul" :
                holder.contenedor.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,0, 0, 255));
                break;
            case "Morado" :
                holder.contenedor.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,255, 0, 255));
                break;
            case "Blanco" :
                holder.contenedor.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,255, 255, 255));
                break;
            case "Negro" :
                holder.contenedor.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(255,0, 0, 0));
                break;
        }

        switch (textcolor) {
            case "Naranja":
                holder.titxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 164, 40));
                holder.platxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 164, 40));
                holder.posetxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 164, 40));
                holder.formatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 164, 40));
                holder.avatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 164, 40));
                holder.vectxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 164, 40));
                break;
            case "Rojo":
                holder.titxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 30, 30));
                holder.platxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 30, 30));
                holder.posetxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 30, 30));
                holder.formatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 30, 30));
                holder.avatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 30, 30));
                holder.vectxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 252, 30, 30));
                break;
            case "Amarillo":
                holder.titxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 240, 76));
                holder.platxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 240, 76));
                holder.posetxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 240, 76));
                holder.formatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 240, 76));
                holder.avatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 240, 76));
                holder.vectxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 240, 76));
                break;
            case "Verde":
                holder.titxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 42, 211, 56));
                holder.platxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 42, 211, 56));
                holder.posetxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 42, 211, 56));
                holder.formatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 42, 211, 56));
                holder.avatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 42, 211, 56));
                holder.vectxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 42, 211, 56));
                break;
            case "Azul":
                holder.titxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 32, 232, 225));
                holder.platxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 32, 232, 225));
                holder.posetxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 32, 232, 225));
                holder.formatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 32, 232, 225));
                holder.avatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 32, 232, 225));
                holder.vectxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 32, 232, 225));
                break;
            case "Morado":
                holder.titxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 182, 104, 255));
                holder.platxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 182, 104, 255));
                holder.posetxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 182, 104, 255));
                holder.formatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 182, 104, 255));
                holder.avatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 182, 104, 255));
                holder.vectxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 182, 104, 255));
                break;
            case "Blanco":
                holder.titxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
                holder.platxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
                holder.posetxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
                holder.formatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
                holder.avatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
                holder.vectxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
                break;
            case "Negro":
                holder.titxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 0,0,0));
                holder.platxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 0,0,0));
                holder.posetxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 0,0,0));
                holder.formatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 0,0,0));
                holder.avatxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 0,0,0));
                holder.vectxtlist.setTextColor(Color.argb(255, 0,0,0));
                break;

        }

    }
```

and that's it

if you have any problem, make sure you don't messed it up with the color references
(`Color.parseColor("#000000")` didn't worked for me in this case)